# Unable to use database in mysql (access denied)

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to get started with the following github package: [py-gameday](https://github.com/wellsoliver/py-gameday).

I installed mysql with `brew mysql` and created a root password:

```
> mysqladmin -u root password 'xxx'
```

I then created a user:

```
> mysql -uroot -p 
Enter password: xxx
CREATE USER 'josh'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'yyy';
```

Just in case, I reset the password again:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'josh'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('yyy');
```

and I then updated `mydb.ini` with:

```
[db]
user=josh
password=yyy
db=gameday
```

I finally tried running the following:

```
$ mysql -D gameday < gameday.sql -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'josh'@'localhost' to database 'gameday'
```

In this last step, I tried entering 'xxx' and 'yyy', but none of them worked. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to GRANT access for the user 'josh' to the database 'test'.

```
GRANT ALL ON test.* TO 'josh'@'localhost';
```

As long as you don't have NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER set, you can skip the CREATE USER... the following will create the USER and GRANT access in one hit...

```
GRANT ALL ON test.* TO 'josh'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'yyy';
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the problem, although I now run into a new one. To not confuse matters, I created it on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19360910/unable-to-use-database-in-mysql-unknown-database) thread.

Answer (score 1):

You have to also set privileges for that user

```
GRANT ALL ON test.* TO 'josh'@'localhost';
```