# Unable to use database in mysql (unknown database)

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get started with the following github package: [py-gameday](https://github.com/wellsoliver/py-gameday).

I installed mysql with `brew mysql` and created a root password:

```
> mysqladmin -u root password 'xxx'
```

I then created a user:

```
> mysql -uroot -p 
Enter password: xxx
CREATE USER 'josh'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'yyy';
```

and just in case, I reset the password again:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'josh'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('yyy');
```

and grant permissions:

```
GRANT ALL ON gameday.* TO 'josh'@'localhost';
```

and I then updated `mydb.ini` with:

```
[db]
user=josh
password=yyy
db=gameday
```

I finally tried running the following:

```
$ mysql -D gameday < gameday.sql -p
Enter password: yyy
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'gameday'
```

Why doesn't it work? I have a `gameday.sql` sitting there on the directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to physically create the database in mysql. Currently the `gameday.sql` is just a set of commands to run in the mysql database which probably creates a bunch of tables.

You'll need to use `CREATE DATABASE gameday;` in mysql, then give `josh` permissions to write to that database. Then the `mysql -D -p gameday < gameday.sql -p` command should work.